# Is it possible to use String.Split() when NewLine is the delimiter?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I have a question which asks me to calculate something from an input file.  The problem is, the lines in the file don't use any special character as delimiter, like `,` or `|`. I will show it down below.

```
Data Communication 
20 
Visual Basic  
40
```

The output I need to write to another file should look like this:

```
Data communication 20
Visual Basic 40

Total Books : 60
```

The problem is, how can I specify the delimiter? Like when there is a symbol as in `strArray = strLine.Split(",")`. Since there is nothing I can use as delimiter, how can I split the file content?

Comment: Should work okay, but it's a poor way to parse delimited data, even regular csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real need to split the text in the input file, when you can read a file line by line using standard methods.

You can use, e.g., a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) to read the lines from the source file, check whether the current line is just text or it can be converted to a number, using [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) and excluding empty lines.

Here, when the line read is not numeric, it's added as a `Key` in a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`, unless it already exists (to handle duplicate categories in the source file).
If the line represents a number, it's added to the `Value` corresponding to the category `Key` previously read, stored in a variable named `previousLine`.

This setup can handle initial empty lines, empty lines in the text body and duplicate categories, e.g.,

```
Data Communication
20 
Visual Basic  
40

C#  
100
Visual Basic  
10
Other stuff
2

C++
10000
Other stuff
1
```

If a number is instead found in the first line, it's treated as a category.
Add any other check to handle a different structure of the input file.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq

Dim basePath = "[Path where the input file is stored]"
Dim booksDict = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim currentValue As Integer = 0
Dim previousLine As String = String.Empty

Using sr As New StreamReader(Path.Combine(basePath, "Books.txt"))

    While sr.Peek > -1
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine().Trim()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
            If Integer.TryParse(line, currentValue) AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(previousLine)) Then
                booksDict(previousLine) += currentValue
            Else
                If Not booksDict.ContainsKey(line) Then
                    booksDict.Add(line, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        previousLine = line
    End While
End Using
```

Now, you have a Dictionary where the Keys represent categories and the related Value is the sum of all books in that category.

You can [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) each KeyValuePair of the Dictionary and transform it into a string that represents the Key and its Value (`Category:Number`).
Here, also [OrderBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) is used, to order the categories alphabetically, in ascending order; it may be useful.

[File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines) is then called to store the strings generated.
In the end, a new string is appended to the file, using [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext), to write the sum of all books in all categories. The [Sum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) method sums all the Values in the Dictionary.

```
Dim newFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "BooksNew.txt")

File.WriteAllLines(newFilePath, booksDict.
    Select(Function(kvp) $"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}").OrderBy(Function(s) s))
File.AppendAllText(newFilePath, vbCrLf & "Total Books: " & booksDict.Sum(Function(kvp) kvp.Value).ToString())
```

The output is:

```
C#:100
C++:10000
Data Communication:20
Other stuff:3
Visual Basic:50

Total Books: 10173
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.. `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` will read the whole file and split into an array based on newlines, so you'll get an array of 4 elements. You can process it with a flipflop boolean to get alternate lines, or you can try and parse the line to a number and if it works, then its a number and if not, it's a string. If it's a number take the string you remembered (using a variable) from the previous loop

```
Dim arr = File.ReadALlLines(...)

Dim isStr = True
Dim prevString = ""

For Each s as String in arr

  If isStr Then 
    prevString = s
  Else
    Console.WriteLine($"The string is {prevString} and the number is {s}")
  End If

  'flip the boolean
  isStr = Not isStr
Next s
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `File.ReadAllLines` to get an array containing each line in the file. Since the size of the file could be larger than the sample shown, I am using a `StringBuilder`. This save having to throw away and create a new string on each iteration of the loop.

I am using interpolated strings indicated by the `$` preceding the quotes. This allows you to insert variables into the string surrounded by braces.

Note the `Step 2` in the `For` loop. `i` will increment by 2 instead of the default 1.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim total As Integer
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 2 Step 2
        sb.AppendLine($"{lines(i)} {lines(i + 1)}")
        total += CInt(lines(i + 1))
    Next
    sb.AppendLine($"Total Books: {total}")
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```