# “Input string was not in a correct format” while parsing the content of a file

Tags: vb.net

I need help, I don't know why the array for the quantity in my input file `strArr(1)` having an error that says that the input string was not in a correct format.

```
Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
Dim objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\StationeryFolder\output.txt")
Dim strLine As String
Dim strName As String
Dim intQuantity As Integer
Dim intTotal As Integer
Dim strArr() As String

If IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\user\Desktop\StationeryFolder\input.txt") = True Then
    objReader = IO.File.OpenText("C:\Users\user\Desktop\StationeryFolder\input.txt")
Else
    MsgBox("File is not exist")
    Close()
End If

Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
    strLine = objReader.ReadLine()
    strArr = strLine.Split("  ")
    strName = strArr(0)
    intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(strArr(1)) //this is where the error occurs
    intTotal = intTotal + intQuantity
    lstDisplay.Items.Add(strName & "    " & intQuantity.ToString())
    objWriter.WriteLine(strName & "     " & intQuantity.ToString())
Loop

lstDisplay.Items.Add("Total Quantity of Stationeries are: " & intTotal.ToString())
objWriter.WriteLine("Total Quantity of Stationeries are: " & intTotal.ToString())
objReader.Close()
objWriter.Close()
```

Inside the input file:

```
Markers   
15
Pens     
25
```

Comment: Do you have one item per line as in the sample you posted? In that case, what are you splitting? See the methods [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65372870/7444103) in an almost identical question.

Comment: If you have instead both the description an a value in the same line, post a sample that reflects the real content, plus some details on the format: if the description can contain more than one word, for example.

Comment: Little confusing, you are using ReadLine , then split that line, but in your example, there is only one item per line ... the second object you want is in second line. you can try to don't split to see the result.

Comment: I have corrected this code before. Are you deleting questions?

Comment: Your `strArr = strLine.Split("  ")`  is sending a string with 2 characters to the `Split`method. Since there is no overload of `Split` that will take only a `String`, I can only assume that it is converting this to a `Char` array. If you had Option Strict On, which it always should be, this wouldn't even compile. It appears that the lines in your file do not have any spaces so how could there possibly be 2 elements in the resulting array?

Comment: Stream objects need to be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I used the .net `File` class instead of streams. `ReadAllLine` returns an array of the lines in the file. I used a `StringBuilder` which is mutable (changeable) unlike a String. Saves the code from creating and throwing away several strings. I have used interpolated strings indicated by the `$` before the quotes. This allows inserting variables directly into the string surrounded by braces.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim inputPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\StationeryFolder\input.txt"

    If Not IO.File.Exists(inputPath) Then
        MsgBox("File does not exist")
        Close()
    End If

    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputPath)
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 2 Step 2
        lstDisplay.Items.Add($"{lines(i)}    {lines(i + 1)}")
        sb.AppendLine($"{lines(i)}    {lines(i + 1)}")
        total += CInt(lines(i + 1))
    Next

    lstDisplay.Items.Add($"Total Quantity of Stationeries are: {total}")
    sb.AppendLine($"Total Quantity of Stationeries are: {total}")

    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\user\Desktop\StationeryFolder\output.txt", sb.ToString)
End Sub
```